# How to create DOM for XML without using DOM parser

Tags: xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I want to create a DOM of a huge xml file using a parser. But DOM parsers are memory hoggers. So I wanted to know is there any alternative for DOM parsers which will not use much memory but I can create DOM out of it. Also please suggest if there is any other efficient algorithms or parsers for handling such situation.

Comment: The parser doesn't fill up your memory but the DOM itself does.

Comment: Ok.But while parsing does it  not create many overheads which also stored in the memory besides the DOM?

Comment: Why should a parser do that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason a DOM parser uses lots of memory is because a DOM uses lots of memory.

There are tree models that take less memory than DOM, for example JDOM2 or XOM. They are also much more user-friendly.

There are many other techniques for reducing the memory used when processing XML, but it all depends on what you want to do with the XML once it is parsed.

Comment: I want to diff two xml s to be precise. My plan is to parse the xml s, store them as DOM and compare them.So after parsing I want to compare the xml s.

Comment: Well, differencing is quite an art in itself. Why not get a tool designed for the job, like DeltaXML, rather than trying to reinvent the wheel? And if you do want to implement it yourself, why not use a high-level language designed for processing XML, like XSLT or XQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, DOM is a memory hogger, JDOM or DOM4j also have similar issues... I am not faimilar with JDOM2, but it appears to have many commonalities with JDOM..

The fundamental cause for DOM's memory issue is actually the inherent limitation of allocating many small, discrete objects...

VTD-XML is a drastic departure from DOM, JDOM and DOM4J. Instead of allocating a lot of small objects, it allocates large memory blocks internally, and allows for dramatical memory savings... while still retaining majority of random access capabilites, and XPath

So my suggestion is not to build a DOM at all...there is really nothing you can do with DOM that you can't with vtd-xml